# LWUIT Touch devices scrolling issue

Tags: java, java-me, touch, lwuit

I want to implement **lazy loading** in **touch devices** using **LWUIT**. On key devices I successfully implemented lazy loading using the **keyDown()** event of the device but on touch devices this not work.

When user scroll the list in touch device how can I know **how much user scroll** and **how many item I have to add for visible area** and remove item from the top of the list and add item at bottom of the list? Is there any method in LWUIT by using that I can check how much user scroll and how many item I have to visible?

And how can I detect how much component to visible because device to device scroll speed and how many component to visible is also change? If there is any method in LWUIT to find how many component should visible next when user drag then it can help.

Answer (score 2):

You should have used the list model to lazily load data and not the key events, that would have worked for everything. Look at the Makeover demo where we implemented lazy loading in the model layer.

Model entries that aren't visible won't be called in a list.

[Eric Coolman wrote a great tutorial](http://gadgets.coolman.ca/lazy-loading-implementing-an-infinite-list-in-codename-one/) on how to do this in Codename One, for streaming the entries from Twitter.

Comment: Hi Shai thanks for your answer.i want to do lazy loading because of memory usage on low end devices. I want to load only 5 or 6 data at item and as user scroll on touch devices data is loaded and appended at end and data at top will get removed so memory consumption will be stable and not get out of memory error on low end j2me devices. In key devices we implement easily with the help of key Down and key up event for data load and remove operation. Now i want to implement same thing for the touch devices.

Comment: If you are using Lists you can achieve that exact same effect using the instructions above.

Comment: Thanks Shai for your quick reply. Currently i am using multiple  container to build a list. Are you talking about Default List of LWUIT? In default LWUIT List render is called multiple time. Can default list give Out of Memory on low end devices because of multiple time call to create image and fill data on particular list row. Can we implement our own logic same like List?

Comment: List is designed to be of a lower overhead but its quite different in behavior from standard Component/Container. Since touch scrolling requires a properly laid out and ready Container you won't be able to implement what you want any other way as far as I can tell without getting REALLY deep into LWUIT code.